# How to get notice when ListView Items present?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a `ListView` and `ListBox`. `ListView` shows some data, which binding to a list.
And `ListBox` is used as a menu. when I click a item in menu, I change the binded source list, thus `ListView` shows the updated content.
Now I want to get all visible items in the `ListView` through the way:

```
var scrollViewer = GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(myListViewControl);
if (scrollViewer != null)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Visible Item Start Index:{0}", scrollViewer.VerticalOffset);
     Console.WriteLine("Visible Item Count:{0}", scrollViewer.ViewportHeight);
}
```

So I subscribe some events. For example, `ValueChanged` and `SizeChanged` event of `ScrollBar`, `SelectionChanged` event of `ListBox` and binded list property `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

But I just get the previous view's `scrollViewer.VerticalOffset` after `ListBox` `SelectionChanged` event raise every time.I think when I recieve the event notification, `ListView` has not present view.

So, my question is, how to get the updated view's `scrollViewer.VerticalOffset` and `scrollViewer.ViewportHeight` immediately instead of the previous view's? I need to request server by these items.

Comment: have you tried handling the `ScrollChanged` event o `ScrollViewer` instead?

Comment: have you tried LayoutUpdated event?